# Machine Learning tools for python dealing with potential matches for terms within textual data

Tags: python, machine-learning

I'm planning to write a script that reads in text input data. This would consist of certain terms e.g "red car".

What machine learning tools for python should I use if I wanted to identify potential matches to a term in my text input data within a database of terms and sentences.

For example, I would want similarly spelled terms (e.g mis-spelled terms) like "redd car" to  be identified and listed in the output of my script.

Edit 1: I have a method of identifying string similarity using [FuzzyWuzzy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fuzzywuzzy) to return a number representation of two strings's similarity to each other. My question would be now how to divide the words in the database into "similar" and "not similar" using machine learning approaches.

Comment: please explain what you mean by "similar sounding terms", similar in what regards: pronunciation, spelling, or meaning?

Comment: Apologies, I mean in terms of spelling.

Comment: you could look into [string metrics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_metric) - perhaps, you try a composite of these metrics do to a fuzzy match (for python, take a look at: [fuzzywuzzy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fuzzywuzzy)). it really isn't clear from the question why you need training data, which is more of concept used for supervised learning. if you provide more info about what your goal is, then we can better help.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing much of your setup I would recommend using [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/) packages for your project. It has support for almost every aspect of machine learning including but not limited to:

- Classification
- Regression
- Clustering
- Dimensionality reduction
- Model selection
- Preprocessing